# Showing .net object from al class on a .cshtml page

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to .NET and I'm trying to show my json on my .cshtml page and I don't know how to get it there. I also want to test what this class gives back since I don't know if it will work because I am getting the json from my localhost java ee backend. I am using an MVC template.

```
class Evaluatie
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/projecten/api/leerlingen"));

        var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Leerling>(response);
    }

    public class Leerling
    {
        public string inschrijvingsNummer { get; set; }
        public string naam { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string evaluatieNummer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the .cshtml page looks like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Evaluaties";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
```

this is my json:

```
[{"inschrijvingsNummer":"0001","naam":"Joske Vermeulen","email":"joske.vermeulen@hotmail.be","evaluatieNummer":"270"},
{"inschrijvingsNummer":"0002","naam":"Kamiel Spiesses","email":"Kamiel.spiesses@gmail.com","evaluatieNummer":"370"}]
```

Comment: Are you using MVC? Can you show your controller code OR how you are rendering the view?

Comment: Where is your controller that render your View?

Comment: I think you can use `JsonResult` type of method instead of `ActionResult`

Comment: one problem is that your json is for a list of objects, but you are trying to deserialize a single object.  You need to change you deserialization code to var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Leerling>>(response);

Comment: Well i have no idea how to use the code from my Evaluatie.cs to get it on my about.cshtml, do I put it in the controller? Do i use another controller? What do I need for it to work?

Comment: Thank you @Fran, I haven't tested the code yet since I don't know how to show it in my browser.

Comment: @JamieR I used the MVC template and I'm editing the About page so it uses the HomeController.cs
the controller looks like this:
`public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method to your HomeController.

```
    public JsonResult TestJson()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/projecten/api/leerlingen"));

        var someObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Leerling>>(response);

        return new JsonResult() {Data = someObject, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }
```

This is going to deserialize your json and re-serialize it in the JsonResult.  This can be access with your path /home/TestJson.

If you just want to see the json string in the About view

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        var client = new WebClient();
        ViewBag.Json = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/projecten/api/leerlingen"));

        return View();
    }
```

Then just call the ViewBag in the About view like this

```
<p>@ViewBag.Json</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'll need to try and parse it so it looks better and then I need to add 2 User Roles, so not everyone can see it not sure how to do that but I'll try. Still thank you very much.